# How do I keep the app open between UITests in Xcode

Tags: xcode-ui-testing

I have a series of UITests I want to run as individual tests but I don't want to relaunch the app between each test.  How can I launch the app and keep it open so it doesn't shutdown and restart between tests.

I tried putting XCUIApplication().launch() in init() but got an error.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible, but if it is, I suspect it should have something to do with the teardown() code.  I don't know too much about it and a quick google search resulted in no real help.  I hope you have better luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `setUp()` method, remove `[[[XCUIApplication alloc] init] launch];` and put it into the first test you will be performing.

For eg.,

If you have tests: testUI(), testUIPart2(), testUIPart3(), etc., and it runs in this order, put `[[[XCUIApplication alloc] init] launch];` into the first line of testUI() and no where else.

Comment: *headdesk*  So obvious.  I thought the app was closing do to some magic the tools not that it was closing down simply because it was relaunching.

Answer (score 9):

To improve on @James Goe's answer -

To avoid all those relaunches, but keep the ability to run individual tests - and not care about the order in which they're run - you can:

```
class MyTests: XCTestCase {
    static var launched = false

    override func setUp() {
        if (!MyTests.launched) {
            app.launch()
            MyTests.launched = true
        }
```

(Of course, now that you're not relaunching your app you have to care much more about state, but that's another story. It's certainly faster.)

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old, but XCTestCase has a class func for `setup()` and `tearDown()` that executes before the first test, and after the last test completes. If you create your `XCUIApplication()` as a singleton (say XCUIAppManager), you could put your `XCUIAppManager.shared.launchApp()` call within the `override class func setup()` method... this will only launch the app once per XCTestCase (contains multiple tests)

```
override class func setUp() { // 1.
    super.setUp()
    // This is the setUp() class method.
    // It is called before the first test method begins.
    // Set up any overall initial state here.
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/understanding_setup_and_teardown_for_test_methods

Example app manager singleton implementation:

```
import XCTest

class XCUIAppManager {
    static let shared = XCUIAppManager()
    let app = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.something.yourAppBundleIdentifierHere")
    private(set) var isLaunched = false

    private init() {}

    func launchApp() {
        app.launch()
        isLaunched = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I think setUp method is called with every tests in a TestCase, tearDown is called when a test in TestCase finish?

Comment: The `setUp()` and `tearDown()` instance methods WILL be called for each test method. However, the `class func setUp()` and `class func tearDown()` class methods are only called once -> see the apple docs link in my answer

Comment: I just tried this and the app still quits after the first test file completes when running XCUITests  Xcode 11.3

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to allow both common or non-common app launches on each test.

you can do it by creating your custom `XCUIApplication` and include state in your app launches as shown below.

```swift
import XCTest

class MyUIApplication: XCUIApplication {
    private(set) var isLaunched = false
    static let shared = MyUIApplication()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
        
        // add your launch arguments and environment keys
        launchArguments += ["isRunningTests"]
        launchEnvironment["state"] = "InitState"
    }

    func launchIfNeeded(at state: AppState) {
        if !isLaunched {
            launch(at: state)
        }
    }

    func launch(at state: AppState) {
        switch state {
        case .home:
            launchEnvironment["state"] = "InitState"
        ...
        }

        launch()
        isLaunched = true
    }
}
```

An example of test case with the above solution:

```swift
class MyViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {
    let app = VFGUIApplication.shared

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        app.launchIfNeeded(at: .home)
    }
}
```

This is preferable specially if you are working with a team and you want to make sure that launches are executed properly based on pre-defined `launchArguments` and `launchEnvironment`, etc.