# Is there any way to avoid the closing of the application for each test executed?

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I am working with XCodeUI, I already have the tests created using the POM pattern but for each test that is executed the application closes and opens again to execute the next test, is there any way to avoid this application closing and everything is executed without to close and open the application for each test?

Comment: You want the state left over from one test to impinge upon another test?

Comment: yesm i don't know it this is possible @matt

Comment: It’s pretty anti-pattern, which is why it’s not nicely supported. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293487/how-do-i-keep-the-app-open-between-uitests-in-xcode contains some discussion and ideas on how you might do it.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have app.launch() in your setUp()

Replace it with app.activate(), and your app won't close every time.